# How to set a local smtp server to send anonymous e-mails

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix, smtp

My attempt is to send an e-mail from [non_existing_email@address.com] to [address]@[random.com], which exists, in an unauthorized way.

I have tried generic solutions i.e.

1) which is the basic case and could not make it work.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect('localhost:25')
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, m + msg)
server.close()
```

and
2) only works for gmail recipients. I am looking for its generalized edition where recipient's address can be any address.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25')
server.starttls()
server.ehlo("example.com")
server.mail(fromaddr)
server.rcpt(toaddrs[0])
server.data(msg)
server.quit()
```

Is there a possible way to have such anonymity?

Comment: If you're trying to create a spambot/spam mail server, you may not receive much help here. If I misunderstand your intent, I apologize.

Comment: What a shallow approach. If I were planning such thing, would I post it on askubuntu? NO. Purpose is pure anonymity.

Comment: Additionally, one might consider that it's working for gmail based addresses. That would be sufficient to hack, with your rationale.

Comment: You say you "could not make it work", but not what happened. You need to add more detail for us to understand the problem.